# String formatting not working inside for-if-do command for batch processing

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, string-formatting

I am trying to execute a windows batch command inside my python script using os.system(). My command looks like

```
os.system('''for %i in ("D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository\\..\\p3\\*.aar") do if exist "D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~nxi" copy "%~i" "D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~ni.aar" /Y ''')
# it works fine...when path "D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository" is hard coded
```

.This works perfectly. However now my requirement is that instead of hardcoding the directory path, i want to pass it as a variable "REPO_PATH" and use the string format capability of python to pass this path in my command . Therefore my command should be

```
os.system('''for %i in ("{}\\..\\p3\\*.aar".format(REPO_PATH)) do if exist "{}\\com\\aws\\sdk\\%~ni\\%~nxi".format(REPO_PATH) 
 copy "%~i" "{}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~ni.aar".format(REPO_PATH) /Y ''')`
```

To my surprise this command does not work. I have included my python script file too.  What am I missing here?? Any help. My Python script file is shown below along with the outputs I get as comments next to the commands.

```
import os,sys
REPO_PATH="D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository"
print(REPO_PATH)


os.system('''for %i in ("D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository\\..\\p3\\*.aar") do if exist "D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~nxi" copy "%~i" "D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~ni.aar" /Y ''')
# it works fine...when path "D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository" is hard coded


os.system('''for %i in ("{}\\..\\p3\\*.aar".format(REPO_PATH)) do if exist "{}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~nxi".format(REPO_PATH) copy "%~i" "{}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~ni.aar".format(REPO_PATH) /Y ''')
#it gives error saying  ""{}\..\p3\*.aar".format was unexpected at this time."
```

Comment: That's not a bash command at all -- `cmd` is a completely unrelated shell with a syntax that isn't even in the same family.

Comment: @charls I have tried out that approach but. The printed paths were as expected

Comment: If you want Python to format printf-like stuff, say, `%i`, use the `%` operator and provide some data: `'hello %s' % 'world'`.

Comment: @AbhijotMann, whatever you tried was not accurately representing what your code actually did. Run the code in the first section of my answer (which is copied-and-pasted from your question, with the only change being the switch from `os.system` to `print`) and look at its output.

Comment: @9000, that's the old Python 2 mode. Using `format()` is the Python 3 approach, also backported to 2.x, and is generally preferred; it lets you do several replacements of an argument passed only once, to give you a concrete idea of why it's better. (See the use of `{0}` in my answer pointing to the 0-th/first positional argument to `format()`).

Comment: @AbhijotMann, ...btw, note that in general before you can substitute data into a shell command without introducing security risks, that data needs to be quoted. For UNIX platforms, `shlex.quote()` is the right way to do this in Python 3; I'm no Windows expert, so I can't tell you what the right practice is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a safe way to pass filenames to a shell at all. Ignoring that, though, the immediate problem is that you're putting `.format(REPO_PATH)` inside the shell code, whereas it needs to be executed by the Python interpreter, not by `cmd.exe`.

Compare:

```
# your original code, with print() instead of os.system(), to show the bug
REPO_PATH="D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository"
print('''for %i in ("{}\\..\\p3\\*.aar".format(REPO_PATH)) do if exist "{}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~nxi".format(REPO_PATH) copy "%~i" "{}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~ni.aar".format(REPO_PATH) /Y ''')
```

to

```
# only one format(), on the entire string, to *fix* the bug
REPO_PATH="D:\\u\\demo4\\v2\\repository"
print('''for %i in ("{0}\\..\\p3\\*.aar") do if exist "{0}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~nxi" copy "%~i" "{0}\\com\\aws\sdk\\%~ni\\%~ni.aar" /Y '''.format(REPO_PATH))
```

...you'll see that the former has `.format(REPO_PATH)` inside the script text being passed to the shell, whereas the latter actually replaces the instances before invoking the shell.